# Google Charts adding 2nd query(2nd line)

Tags: php, mysql, charts, linechart

First of all the chart I made is working, but now I need to change 1 thing and then everyone is happy. I have made a chart with 1 query it looks like this one:
[image]

Now i need to ad another line with an 2nd query in this linechart

something like this one for example(example from google not mine!) [image]

---

I made some progress and made this. And yes I still miss one little thing with the second query all the lines are the same. That is not the plan or purpose. The second line (query)show only the first result of the query

The first query is good it does what I want but not the 2nd query.

like this one:
[image]

This is the new script:

```
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

          ['Weekly TotalExcl', 'Previous', 'Current'],

        <?php 

            $query = "SELECT COUNT(o.id_customer) AS Orders, SUM(o.total_paid_tax_excl) AS TotalExcl, AVG(o.total_paid_tax_excl) AS Average, IFNULL(CONCAT(c.company), 'W') AS Customer FROM ex.ps_orders o LEFT JOIN ex.ps_customer c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer WHERE YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) GROUP BY c.company ORDER BY TotalExcl DESC limit 10";

            $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

              echo "['".$row['Customer']."',";

              $query2 = "SELECT COUNT(o.id_customer) AS Orders, SUM(o.total_paid_tax_excl) AS TotalExcl, AVG(o.total_paid_tax_excl) AS Average, IFNULL(CONCAT(c.company), 'W') AS Customer FROM ex.ps_orders o LEFT JOIN ex.ps_customer c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer WHERE YEAR(o.date_add) = YEAR(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) GROUP BY c.company ORDER BY TotalExcl DESC limit 10";

              $exec2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
              $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec2);

              echo $row2['Average'];

              $rvisits = $row['TotalExcl']-$row2['Customer'];

              echo ",".$rvisits."],";
            }
     ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 2},
          hAxis: {minValue: 0},
          bars: 'vertical',
          colors: ['#4682B4','#FF4500'],
          animation: { "startup": true, duration: 2000, easing: 'in' },
          allowHtml: true,
        };

        var material  = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart17'));
        material .draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }

    </script>
```

Comment: to add a second line, you need another column in the array data fed to `arrayToDataTable`, something like --> `echo "['".$row['Date']."',".$row['query1_total'].",".$row['query2_total']."],";`